# How can i solve font downloadable error "downloadable font: OS/2: bad linegap:"?

Tags: magento-1.9, font-family

```
How can i solve font downloadable error for magento site show as follow:
```

> downloadable font: OS/2: bad linegap: -32 (font-family: "ThemeIcons"
>   style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1) source:
>   http://yourdomain.com/skin/frontend/yourtheme/default/fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.woff?387osh

Screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this problem by removing space gape as:
Old Code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ThemeIcons';
    src:url('../../../fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.eot?387osh');
    src:url('../../../fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.eot?#iefix387osh') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../../../fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.woff?387osh') format('woff'),
        url('../../../fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.ttf?387osh') format('truetype'),
        url('../../../fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.svg?387osh#ThemeIcons') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

New Code Just Remove Space before ,url(..):

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'ThemeIcons';
    src:url('../../../fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.eot?387osh');
    src:url('../../../fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.eot?#iefix387osh') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../../../fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.woff?387osh') format('woff'),url('../../../fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.ttf?387osh') format('truetype'),url('../../../fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.svg?387osh#ThemeIcons') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: That's nuts, it works!

Answer (score 2):

Ok :)
"Bad line gap "
error indicates the use of one deprecated browser prefixes like:
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap which isn't required as of Firefox 3.0 
You have to inspect your font stylesheet on the line 2 to see exact prefix.
After line :

> font-weight:

/*remove or comment out this code line (-moz-something)*/

And see if it helps.

Comment: I solve this problem by removing space gape as:

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if this dir exists 
http://yourdomain.com/skin/frontend/yourtheme/default/fonts/themeicons/
If not you have to create it and upload missing font file called ThemeIcons.woff

Comment: Actually it may not font missing because i can see all font icon.              Yes exist this font:http://devonbd.com/skin/frontend/devon/sslw/fonts/themeicons/ThemeIcons.woff